# MySQL user variables and SUM function

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to do some calculations within a SELECT query, using user variables to do so. This works fine, until I start using functions like `SUM` to collect data from joined tables.

Simplified example:

```
SET @a = 1;

SELECT @a := SUM(1 + 1) AS sum, @a
```

Result:

```
+------+------+
| sum  | @a   |
+------+------+
|    2 |    1 |
+------+------+
```

I'd expect @a to be 2 here.

Other example:

```
SELECT @b := SUM(1 + 1) AS sum, @b;
```

```
+------+------+
| sum  | @b   |
+------+------+
|    2 | NULL |
+------+------+
```

Now it's NULL, because @b wasn't SET before the query.

It seems that the variable isn't overwritten with the result of the SUM function. Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: what you really want to achieve

Comment: @AnkitSharma: calculations within a SELECT query. So I need to use the result of e.g. `SUM(1+1)` in further calculations. In stead of using `SUM(1+1)` over and over again, I'd like to store it in a variable _once_, e.g. `@a`, and then re-use `@a` later on.

Comment: @AnkitSharma: I can't. This is just a simplified example. The SUM calculates the sum of various amounts collected from joined tables in the query itself.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As stated [in the documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/user-variables.html):

As a general rule, **you should never assign a value to a user variable and read the value within the same statement**. You might get the results you expect, but this is not guaranteed. The order of evaluation for expressions involving user variables is undefined and may change based on the elements contained within a given statement; in addition, this order is not guaranteed to be the same between releases of the MySQL Server. In `SELECT @a, @a:=@a+1, ...`, you might think that MySQL will evaluate `@a` first and then do an assignment second. However, changing the statement (for example, by adding a `GROUP BY`, `HAVING`, or `ORDER BY` clause) may cause MySQL to select an execution plan with a different order of evaluation.

To the second part of your question. You can initialize your `@variable` within a query like this (subqueries get evaluated first):

```
SELECT @b := SUM(1 + 1) AS sum, @b FROM (SELECT @b:=0) b
```

Comment: not guaranteed :) the excerpt from the doc that I re-posted explains why. Just don't do it like that in one statement

Comment: Thanks, missed that part in the docs. I thought I'd save me some time by doing calculations in the query itself, using these vars. But if the results are inconsistent, that's not really an option. Since I'm using a whole lot of different variables, that would mean lots of subqueries too, making it way too complex. I guess I'll just have to stick with retrieving the main data with MySQL and use PHP to do the necessary calculations afterwards.

Comment: Actually, the doc statement says not to "assign" and use in same statement, and clarifies further down this is not the same as "set" and use in same statement.  In other words, the docs statement does not apply strictly to your issue, or at least you could work around it by "assigning" an initial value previous to the query with `SET @a = ...`.  The real issue at hand is that MySQL won't assign an aggregate value to your variable until the query is finished.  Your approach will work fine as long as you aren't using it for aggregate values.  That's the real reason the solution works.

Answer (score 1):

It is connected to expression evaluation. In your case you can use a subquery -

```
SET @a = 1;
SELECT sum, @a FROM
  (SELECT @a := SUM(1 + 1) AS sum, @a) t

+------+------+
| sum  | @a   |
+------+------+
|    2 |    2 |
+------+------+
```

More info - [User-Defined Variables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/user-variables.html).

> As a general rule, you should never assign a value to a user variable
>   and read the value within the same statement. You might get the
>   results you expect, but this is not guaranteed. The order of
>   evaluation for expressions involving user variables is undefined and
>   may change based on the elements contained within a given statement;
>   in addition, this order is not guaranteed to be the same between
>   releases of the MySQL Server. In SELECT @a, @a:=@a+1, ..., you might
>   think that MySQL will evaluate @a first and then do an assignment
>   second. However, changing the statement (for example, by adding a
>   GROUP BY, HAVING, or ORDER BY clause) may cause MySQL to select an
>   execution plan with a different order of evaluation.

Comment: How to get a sum of status variable like Com_commit + Com_rollback ?